# Rename all folders with given name in a directory using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to find all folders in the directory by name e.g. `Help` and rename them to `blah`.
Ive tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\dev\foo' -Filter 'Help' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName 'blah'
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Are you sure your Filter is correct?  Your filter only find entries that match exact 'Help' and doesn't find the folder 'GoodHelp' for example because you didn't used `* `.

Comment: sry, where should I put the * ?

Comment: `*` is for any character. So "*Help*" would match every entry that has the word "Help" in it. While the Filter "Help" only matches the folder that exactly is called "Help".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$path = "C:\dev\foo"
$oldName = "Help"
$newName = "blah"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*$oldName*" -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace $oldName, $newName } -WhatIf
```

You were missing the wild card - `"*$oldName*"`. This way you are searching for all folders **containing Help** in the name, not just the one named **Help**. The [-WhatIf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#risk-management-parameter-descriptions) parameter will show you all of the folders that will be renamed without actually renaming them. Remove it when you check if the result will be correct.